# How to plott multiple lines at once on one 2d canvas context? Multiuser sketch pad

Tags: javascript, canvas, socket.io

i have almost made a multiuser sketch pad.
my problem is that since i can only plot one line at a time, the line is jumping in between mouses when 2 or more users draw at the same time,if that makes sense. how can everyuser have his own line?

here is the client JS code. i know it is not written nicely but it is my first attempt at this.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event){
    var startMoveX = new Array();
    var startMoveY = new Array();
    var socket = io.connect();
    socket.on('draw',function(data){
       outDraw(data);
    });

    canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.canvas.width  = window.innerWidth;
    ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    var drawing = false;
    if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|BB|PlayBook|IEMobile|Windows Phone|Kindle|Silk|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){
            var mouseX = Math.round(e.targetTouches[0].clientX);
            var mouseY = Math.round(e.targetTouches[0].clientY);
            var status = document.getElementById('status');
            status.innerHTML = mouseX+" | "+mouseY;
            if(drawing) draw(e)
        }, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", function (e) {
            moveBol = true;
            drawing = true;
            startMoveX.pop();
            startMoveY.pop();
            startMoveX.push(Math.round(e.targetTouches[0].clientX));
            startMoveY.push(Math.round(e.targetTouches[0].clientY));
            ctx.moveTo(startMoveX[0], startMoveY[0]);
        }, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("touchend", function (e) {drawing = false;}, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mousecancel", function (e) {drawing = false;}, false);
    } else {
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
        var mouseX = e.clientX - ctx.canvas.offsetLeft;
        var mouseY = e.clientY - ctx.canvas.offsetTop;
        var status = document.getElementById('status');
        status.innerHTML = mouseX+" | "+mouseY;
        if(drawing) draw(e)
    }, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
            drawing = true;
            moveBol = true;
            startMoveX.pop();
            startMoveY.pop();
            startMoveX.push(e.clientX - ctx.canvas.offsetLeft);
            startMoveY.push(e.clientY - ctx.canvas.offsetTop);
            ctx.moveTo(startMoveX[0], startMoveY[0]);

        }, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {drawing = false;}, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) {drawing = false;}, false);
    }
    function draw(e) {
        if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|BB|PlayBook|IEMobile|Windows Phone|Kindle|Silk|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
            cX = Math.round(e.targetTouches[0].clientX);
            cY = Math.round(e.targetTouches[0].clientY);
        } else {
            cX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
            cY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
        }

        ctx.lineTo(cX, cY);
        ctx.stroke();
        if (moveBol){
            socket.emit('draw',{x:cX,y:cY, preX: startMoveX[0], preY: startMoveY[0]});
            console.log(moveBol);
            moveBol = false;
        } else {
            socket.emit('draw',{x:cX,y:cY});
            console.log(moveBol);
        }
    }
    function outDraw(e) {


        ctx.moveTo(e.preX, e.preY);
        ctx.lineTo(e.x, e.y);
        ctx.stroke();
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

Redraw all currently active draw paths once per frame, keeping and offscreen canvas as the background. When a line is complete draw that line onto the background. Update the display using requestAnimationFrame.

Or

Only draw the line segments using beginPath but you need to keep the previous point.

For example

```
// creates named users that draw to the canvas context ctx
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); // I assume canvas is in scope
var users = {  // cant have users that start with _        
    _addUser(name){  
        if(typeof this[name] === "function"){
            throw new ReferenceError("Can not use the user name '"+name+"'");
        }

        this[name] = {
            lastX : null,
            lastY : null,
            draw(x,y){
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(this.lastX,this.lastY);
                ctx.lineTo(x,y);
                ctx.stroke();
            },                
            addPoint(x,y){
                if(this.lastX !== null){ // new line start
                    this.draw(x,y);
                }
                this.lastX = x;
                this.lastY = y;
            },
            endPoint(x,y){
                if(this.lastX === null){ // incase it is just a point
                    this.lastX = x;
                    this.lastY = y;
                }
                this.draw(x,y);
                this.lastX = null; // end the line
            }
        }
        return this[name];
    }
}

users._createUser("User1");
users._createUser("User2");
```

Then to draw for any user you just need the user name and the point and when the line has ended.

For mousedown and following mousemoves

```
user = "User1";
// mousemove and mousedown events should call
users[user].addPoint(x,y); // add a point if mouse is down
socket.send(JSON.stringify({user, x, y, type : "add"});
```

For mouseup event

```
// when the mouseup 
users[user].endPoint(x,y);
socket.send(JSON.stringify({user, x, y, type : "end"});
```

For getting socket data

```
// if from a socket (should have the user name or id passed with the packet)
// Assuming data is as a JSON string as above
socket.onmessage = function(event){
    var data = JSON.parse(event.data);  // should be wrapped in try catch and security checks

    user = data.user;  // 
    if(users[user]){
        if(data.type === "add"){  // add point
            users[user].addPoint(data.x, data.y); // add a point
        }else if(data.type === "end"){
            users[user].endPoint(data.x, data.y);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much. i couldnt find an answer online ( with my level of knowledge ). i will try this out. you are the best :)